# How to display the second level drop dwon menu in liferay 6.2?

Tags: java, liferay

I have created a page named Welcome and created a page inside Welcome named Demo and inside Demo I created page Demo1 . My question is the second level menu is not displayed onto the navigation bar when I hover Demo. Can you suggest me how to display the same.You can see here:-
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU0ZE.png)

Comment: You will require to add `:hover` effect for that menu and set `display: block;` of ul on it.

Comment: Additionally, Liferay only sets to show 2nd level navigation in its default theme. You need to copy similar loop to extend to further as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a responsibility of the theme to show more levels. The default theme shows one level. If you need more, you'll have to create your own theme and add appropriate CSS for styling/positioning, and the template for creating the navigation markup. When you look at the default theme's templates/navigation.vm, you'll see how this is done in one layer - Velocity is not too generic, so you'll basically just need to embed yet another level in the innermost loop. It should be obvious when you look at the original navigation.vm.

Another option is to make sure that every page contains the navigation portlet, so that you can navigate deeper into the hierarchy from the pages themselves.